# Twitter Bootstrap dropdown on ipad and android doesn't work even with the hack

Tags: android, ipad, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem when I access my software on ipad and android. 
This is the html that doesn't work on ipad. I can't click on the sub-itens

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Export <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <#if  print?exists>
            <li><a href="javascript:print('${print}');">Print in PDF</a></li>
        </#if>
        <#if  printList?exists>
            <li><a href="javascript:print('${printList}');">Print list in PDF</a></li>
        </#if>
        <li><a href="javascript:exportListAt('${targetList}', 2);">Export to Excel</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:exportListAt('${targetList}', 1);">Export to CVS</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:exportListAt('${targetList}', 3);">Export to XML</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I already hack this html with

```
jQuery(document).ready( function (){
            jQuery('.dropdown-toggle')
                .on('touchstart.dropdown', '.dropdown-menu', function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); })
                .on('touchstart.dropdown', '.dropdown-submenu', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); })
    })
```

This error also occur when I access the [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns) site on ipad and android.

What can I do ?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I'm facing the same issue is bootstrap 3.3.4..how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

Recently, Bootstrap 2.2.2 came out and your issue is one of many that has been fixed.

Therefore, a good solution would be to update your Bootstrap version to the latest available.

See [the changelog](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2012/12/08/bootstrap-2-2-2-released/), or [download the latest bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html) directly

I also wrote a short [blog post about this issue](http://forwebonly.com/fix-for-twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-on-ipad-and-iphone/).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should use a `a` element instead of a `button`, like bootstrap docs:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Action
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <!-- dropdown menu links -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

About the bug itself, you should take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4550).

Answer (score 0):

See the discussions about this issue here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9543
Solution: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/c0eabdda9fd8e97f44117bd4bd77dd1344039024
It was originally a Bootstrap problem.

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.4 but still facing this issue in iOS safari..any idea how to resolve it?